# nsis configuration in project.json file does not take effect

Tags: java, spring

I currently use electron version is v7.1.9, the electron-builder version is v21.2.0, the operating system is win10, project.json configuration example：

```
{
  "name": "electron-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "First Electron Demo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start-node": "node .",
    "start-electron": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "admin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "asar": "^2.0.3",
    "electron": "^7.1.9",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "electron-demo",
    "appId": "com.electron.demo",
    "asar": true,
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": ["nsis", "zip"]
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true
    }
  }
}
```

Why oneClick and perMachine in nsis configuration still use default value true and false？

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. please provide a [mcve] illustrating what you want to do and any error you are experiencing. link questions are not very liely to be answered. read [ask] for more information